# Disable merging of cart positions?

Tags: product, cart

Is it possible to disable the merging of same products into one position in the cart?

So when someone adds Product ABC with Qty 1 to the cart, continues shopping and adds the same product again with Qty 2, Magento merges/sums the two products into one position with a Qty of 3.

I’d like to have 2 cart positions with Product ABC with their respective quantities. Is that possible?

The only thing I was finding while looking through the code was `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::merge`, but that doesn't seem to be the right method as it handles merging the carts from a former session after logging in.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just add an option to the product in the event `sales_quote_add_item`:

```
$data['microtime'] = microtime(true);

$product->addCustomOption('do_not_merge', serialize($data));
$item->addOption($product->getCustomOption('do_not_merge'));
```

Comment: Can I dynamically use it for certain type of products (eg: customizable product)

Comment: In the event you can do all checks you want on both: product and quote_item, so yes.

Comment: Where would you put this code? Sorry, trying to perform a patch job and unfamiliar with Magento

Comment: You implement your own module, add an observer, which listens to the event `sales_quote_add_item` , get the quote item just added from the $observer and run the code on the $item.

Comment: @fabian-blechschmidt : I tried this code it is working fine when I add product from product-details page. But when I change the quantity from the 'checkout/cart' this solution is not working.

Comment: @manish_khot That is correct. You need to find an event, which triggers on the update

Answer (score 5):

When adding a product to the cart, this method is called to see if the product with the same options are already in cart. `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::representProduct($product)`. If you override this and make it return `false` every time, you should achieve your desired result. It worked for me in the past.

Comment: Can you plz. sample code and file Path for this ?

Comment: @Tusar. I think you should use the answer provided by Fabian (the accepted answer). It's cleaner and non intrusive. You just have to create an observer for an event. You should find tutorials about that on the web.

Comment: @Marius already I have an event handle checkout_cart_product_add_after how can I have <sales_quote_add_item> handle? Can I add two observer events in a same module observer file, sorry for incorrect terminology I used, but hope you understand what I am asking

Comment: @new_bee_magento. What does your comment have to do with this question or answer? Please don't mix them. Ask a separate question.

Comment: I asked a question and you closed it as duplicate http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-prevent-merging-and-updating-the-quantity-of-a-product-if-the-same-alread and referred this one,

Comment: @new_bee_magento. Then try the accepted answer. The one Fabian provided. It works.

Comment: @Marius please refer my updated question. You put it on hold. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71721/how-to-prevent-merging-and-updating-the-quantity-of-a-product-if-the-same-alread