# Same bundle item twice with different quantity and price

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

I have created a bundle product B1 and its price is 15$. In bundle i have included an item P1 which has zero price increase and quantity is 1. Now I want to add P1 again with price increase of 10$ and default quantity of 2. Basically I want to allow users to buy either 1 P1 in 15$ or 2 P1s in 25$ as a bundle. I tried discount but it does not exactly do what i need. So is there a work around to add same product as bundle item in same option OR any other suggestion to do this.

Comment: Tier Price didn't work for me

Comment: Take a look at the answers [to this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7038/146). It's not exactly what you are looking for, but it may give you and idea on where to start.