# Magento 2: How to Prevent item's quantity from being added

Tags: magento2

Does anybody have clue how to force Magento 2 to not merge into one `CartItem` the same product on adding to cart?

Let's say I would like to sell ropes and my clients might want to order exactly the same rope but with few different lengths (length is defined by quantity). I would like Magento to add certain products (for example by attribute) always as new `CartItem` without checking if the same product is actually in cart.

Does anybody struggle with that problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer you question:

The matching is done by the method `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::representProduct()`.
This method checks if a certain item in the cart is the same as the product you are just adding to the cart.
Making this method always return `false` should make any add to cart action add the product as a new line in the cart.

For this you can use an `aroundPlugin`.

Create a new module and in the `etc/di.xml` add this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
        <plugin name="[module]-quote-item" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Plugin\Quote\Item" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create the file  `[Namespace]/[Module]/Plugin/Quote/Item.php` with this content.

```
<?php
namespace[Namespace]\[Module]\Plugin\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item as QuoteItem;
class Item
{
    public function aroundRepresentProduct(QuoteItem $subject, \Closure $proceed, $product)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or a second option [could be this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7045/146). The code is for Magento 1, but you can adapt it for M2. The event recommended in there, `sales_quote_add_item`, still exists in M2.

To solve your problem, maybe...
If you are planning to sell ropes with fixed lengths maybe you should use configurable products.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's the solution I tried. After debugging I found out that there is also method `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::compare()` which is triggered, in some cases, when you are updating product. That function should be overwritten as well and return false.

Comment: Just want to let you know that even though we have 2 lines in `quote item` table for a same sku, there is only one line in the `quote_item_option` table, the second line regarding the second same SKU is skipped. Any thoughts ?