# Magento 2: How to create multi-line order with same SKU programmatically?

Tags: magento2, orders, programmatically

```php
                    $product
                           ->setPrice($price)
                           ->setSpecialPrice($price)
                           ->setTierPrice([])
                           ->setBasePrice($baseprice)
                           ->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                                /** @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $request */
                           $request = $this->dataFactory->create();
                           $request->setData('qty', (int)$qty)
                           $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
```

I have added the products to quote using the above code. But this merges the row qty for same SKU (as it supposes to).

How to create 2 different item-lines for the same SKU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize method `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::representProduct()` to return false if the product SKU matches your criteria.

Reference post: [Magento 2: How to Prevent item's quantity from being added](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154498/magento-2-how-to-prevent-items-quantity-from-being-added)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to create the item object BEFORE adding it to the quote, instead of directly adding the product to the quote and letting Magento create the item.

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $quoteItem */
$quoteItem = $this->itemFactory->create();
$quoteItem->setPrice(123.33);
$quoteItem->setRowTotal($quoteProduct->getPrice());
$quoteItem->setProductType($quoteProduct->getTypeId());
$quoteItem->setOriginalPrice(123.33);
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice(123.33);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(123.33);
$quoteItem->setQtyOrdered(1);
$quoteItem->setQty(1);
$quoteItem->setProduct($quoteProduct);
$quote->addItem($quoteItem);
```

Original post link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324605/54929